# How to track local variable values in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, global-variables, state

I have been looking for a way to track the value of a program's local and global variables in Javascript. **EDIT/additional information: This program has already been written, so I am retroactively adding this state tracking.** I need to be able to access the current or most recent value of any variable in a program (even in the case when the function containing it has finished running). My current plan is to do the following:

1. Create an AST and add all variables from it to a global "state maintainer" object. Each variable will get a unique entry name in the object so that a variable `x` in a function `foo()` is differentiated from another variable `x` in a function `bar()`.
2. Every time a variable is updated throughout the program, update the value of the variable in the state maintainer object as well.

I'll be injecting code into the JS file that I'm trying to track the values of in order to do this.

I will make sure to keep track of reference assignments and propagate changes to all affected variables when applicable. For example, when `a` is updated below, `b` should get updated as well.

```
var a = 'foo'
var b = a
a = 'bar'
```

Does this approach make sense? Are there any other technical considerations I should pay extra attention to? Are there any libraries that already implement this functionality?

Comment: Your state maintainer sounds a lot like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/)

Comment: You can see the values of local/global variables in browser devtools.  In your code example `b` would not be updated to the value of `a` because of the nature of string assignment in javascript.

Comment: Pretty sure what you're describing will be a lot harder than you think. While you can access values of vars in devtools, AFAIK all browsers make a point to NOT allow programmatical access to this data. You'd probably end up writing your own JavaScript engine on top of the browser's. The closest thing I know of to what you're describing is [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), but it works on object properties, not scope variables. Maybe you could refactor your code to make it work for you...

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use a state management tool like Redux, but if your application is not that huge, you can use rxjs library to manage data streams in your app, this post would help https://medium.com/@mohandere/rxjs-5-in-5-minutes-1c3b4ed0d8cc

If you do not need to use any libraries just implement an observer pattern like in this post [https://jsmanifest.com/observer-pattern-in-javascript](https://jsmanifest.com/observer-pattern-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

As @Ahmed mentioned you have to use third party library for state management, like:

Redux: [Redux Docs](https://redux.js.org/) incase you have a large app

MobX: [MobX Docs](https://mobx.js.org/README.html) in case your app in small or med, and its also easy to learn fast than Redux

and you can maybe use [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) if you don't want to use a new library